# Open Part From Id In Application.e4xmi

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, e4

I have a part that is defined as "Part Descriptor" in the *Application.e4xmi*. And I have the following structure under the "Windows and Dialogs" node:

```
- Trimmed Window 
    - Controls
        - Part Sash Container
            - Part Stack
                Part - A
            - Part - B
```

I tried adding a Placeholder, but it doesn't let me select anything. I know how to add a part programmatically (even though [it's ugly in E4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43782165/open-editor-part-in-e4)), but I want to do it inside the *Application.e4xmi*, because that's the right place.

How do I add the part defined in the "Part Descriptor"?

Comment: I don't think you can. My understanding is that Part Descriptors are solely for parts that you create dynamically.

Comment: @greg-449 But if I don't define it as a part descriptor, I can't open the view programmatically?! Does that mean if I want to have a view that gets opened on startup AND by the user later on I have to define it twice?